# Pass values from controller to a view within a view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can someone please suggest me how to pass the values from a controller to and then to another view inside the template

below is my controller

```
$this->load->model('list_model');
$data['lists']=$this->list_model->loadhome();
$data['body']='content';
$data['right']='right';
$this->load->view('template',$data);
```

below is my template view

```
$this->load->view('includes/header');
$this->load->view($body);
$this->load->view($right);
$this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

what i want to do is pass $data['lists'] from the controller to $this->load->view($body);

can someone tell me how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $this->load->view($body,$lists);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along the lines of:

```
$this->load->model('list_model');
$data['contentData']['lists']=$this->list_model->loadhome();
$data['body']='content';
$data['right']='right';
$this->load->view('template',$data);
```

And your template view:

```
$this->load->view('includes/header');
$this->load->view($body, $contentData);
$this->load->view($right);
$this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

Or if you only need to pass one variable (and didn't want to stack arrays), this would work:

```
$this->load->model('list_model');
$data['lists']=$this->list_model->loadhome();
$data['body']='content';
$data['right']='right';
$this->load->view('template',$data);
```

And your template view:

```
$this->load->view('includes/header');
$this->load->view($body, array('lists'=>$lists));
$this->load->view($right);
$this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could render the body view in your controller and then pass that to your template view.

Controller:

```
$this->load->model('list_model');
$lists = $this->list_model->loadhome();
$data['body_view'] = $this->load->view('content', $lists);
$data['right'] = 'right';
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

Template View:

```
$this->load->view('includes/header');
echo $body_view;
$this->load->view($right);
$this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

More information available at http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/88335/.

Personally, I wouldn't go this route and would just load the four views separately from your controller.  Have you considered doing that?